# How to merge several git branches to the same file?

Tags: git

I made a minimal repository to learn git.
There is a single file

In master I commited that:

```
initial
```

Checkout in a new branch "branch2" and commited that:

```
initial
branch2 addition
```

Checkout to master then checkout to a new branch "branch3" and commited that:

```
initial
branch3 addition
```

The goal is to simulate two persons that want to contribute to master and aren't aware of each other.

I can merge branch2 or branch3 to master but if I try to merge branch2 to master THEN branch3 to master a conflict arises.

How the maintainer of master branch merge several contributions to the same file ?

Answer (score 4):

... conflicts are a part of a developer's life. You need to sit down to see how to put the separate pieces of code together in order to *merge* successfully. A conflict does *not* mean that the code *can't* be merged... it only means that git is not able to merge it *automagically* and needs a little outside help to get it done.